# Ruby = use regex to replace a line in string with blank space

Tags: ruby, arrays, regex

Text file text.txt =

```
--TODAY
This == 5P
That == 4
Them == 4P
Those == 3
--TOMORROW
More == 3P
Yep == 4
```

Start code:

```
file = File.new('text.txt','r')

array = file.readlines

def remove_stuff (variable)
 variable.map! {|delete| delete.gsub(/-*[A-Z]*[a-z]* *=* [^P]?/,' ')}
end

remove_stuff(array)

array.each {|x| puts x}

=>
--TODAY
 P

 P

--TOMORROW
 P
```

Desired result

```
=>

P

P


P
```

What am I missing?  I'm getting a space before the P, and when I match that I lose everything.  I only want the P and blank placeholders for the rest.

Swap out the gsub for this line and you get just the numbers.  It matches --TODAY:

```
gsub(/-*[A-Z]*[a-z]* *=*/,'')
```

Thanks!

Comment: You can't do `array_from_file.gsub(/-*[A-Z]*[a-z]* *=* [^P]?/,' ')}`. Array doesn't have a `gsub` method.

Comment: `--TODAY` and tomorrow don't match the regex.

Comment: I fixed the code above Tin Man.  Sorry I tried to summarize what my code is doing. I'm too much of a newbie for that.

Comment: Check out that edit sin.  That line at the bottom does match, and all I did was remove the P matching stuff.

Comment: @quelleck - Ok, I see. The real problem is the required space, see my post.  If you want to go that route, just make the space optional `-*[A-Z]*[a-z]* *=* *[^P]?`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do it.

```
text =
"--TODAY
This == 5P
That == 4
Them == 4P
Those == 3
--TOMORROW
More == 3P
Yep == 4"

arr = text.split(/\n/)
  #=> ["--TODAY", "This == 5P", "That == 4", "Them == 4P",
  #    "Those == 3", "--TOMORROW", "More == 3P", "Yep == 4"]

r = /^\s*(?<!--).+\s==\s*\d+P$/
arr.map { |s| s[r] ? 'P' : '' }
  #=> ["", "P", "", "P", "", "", "P", ""]
```

In the regex, `(?<!--)` is a "negative-lookbehind" which ensures the string does not begin with two dashes, possibly following some whitespace.

Answer (score 0):

From this breakdown you can see that the minimum it will match is a space.
But there are no spaces in the lines

```
--TODAY
--TOMORROW
```

expanded

```
 -*             # optional
 [A-Z]*         # optional
 [a-z]*         # optional
 [ ]*           # optional
 =*             # optional
 [ ]            # required    <--
 [^P]?          # optional
```

I would broaden your regex to serve a dual purpose.
One to match the  == format, one to match the entire line.

Used this in Multiline mode and it worked on your data.

```
 # (?m)^(?:[^=\n]*=+[^=P\n]*|.*)

 (?m)
 ^ 
 (?:
      [^=\n]* 
      =+
      [^=P\n]* 
   |  
      .* 
 )
```

With this you could just do a replace all (with '') on the string.
Then do a split on newline to get them into an array.